# Which technology for business web application?

Tags: ria

I am pondering on building a CRM for consulting business and am looking for best technology to build on. It will be web based with maybe a plugin that integrates with Outlook. What I don't want is to spend a lot of time doing HTML-fu and CSS-fu just to get basic grids, data entries and so on up. I don't mind picking up a new language. Preference goes to FLOSS projects. If it works with Python + 50 points :)

Projects on my mind:

- Google's GWT - great ecosystem. Pity that it is in old-fashioned Java, but there's [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) too!
- Django -  has all the nice widgets for web, but requires maintaining essentially a dual code base - backend language and front-end. Does not work with JS challenged browsers :(

Any suggestions how to quickly build and maintain web based business app are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

My vote is with Adobe Flex.  Some high-level advantages of flex:

- Browser compatibility: any browser with a flash player will run the site (currently over 90% I believe).  No need to fudge with html/css.
- Data binding: the flex framework's strongest suit is dynamic scalable data binding.
- Server-side technology: Flex can couple with any server-side technology for back-end operations (Java, PHP, RESTful web services, and Coldfusion to name a few)
- Open source:  flex is open source (however, buying the eclipse-based Flash Builder is usually a good idea)
- Customization: every flex component is completely customizable and skinnable.  Nice for business apps that do not want to simply look the same as everyone else.
- Desktop:  Using Adobe AIR Desktop Environment users can interact with the OS.

Comment: Only drawback I see is it's flash - no iPhone/iPad/BlackBerry :(